# How can I pool gradients in Theano?

Tags: theano

I'm using Theano for the first time to build a large statistical model. I'm performing a kind of stochastic gradient descent, but for each sample in the minibatch I need to perform a sampling procedure to compute the gradient. Is there a way in Theano to pool the gradients while I perform the sampling procedure for each datapoint in a minibatch, and only afterward perform the gradient update?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "pool".
When you compute the gradient of your cost wrt some variables, the cost has to be a scalar. So, when using minibatches, you have to combine the individual costs for the examples in the minibatch. That can be done by a sum, a mean, a weighted sum... And then that cost is backpropagated.
The gradient of that cost wrt parameters will correspond (mathematically) to the sum/mean/weigted sum of the individual gradients (on each of the examples), but that is not the way it is computed.
The gradient of that cost wrt intermediate variables that are function of the inputs (hidden representations, etc.) will have the same format as the original minibatch, with the gradient wrt each of the minibatches in a different row.

So, maybe what you want is expressing your final cost as a result of your sampling procedure, and then backpropagate the gradient of that cost.
Or maybe you do not want to backpropagate the gradient of the true cost all the way, and backpropagate something that depends on the gradient instead.
In that case, you can do something like:

```
# minibatch of inputs
inputs = tt.matrix()
interm_result = f(input)
cost = g(interm_result).sum()
grad_wrt_interm_result = th.grad(cost, interm_result)
sampled_grad = sampling_procedure(grad_wrt_interm_result)
grad_wrt_params = th.grad(cost, params,
                          known_grads={inter_result: sampled_grad})
```

That way, you can perform some of the backpropagation to interm_result, then change the gradient wrt inter_result to sampled_grad, and then finish the backpropagation towards the parameters.